# Is RETRACT stream necessary in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

When using RETRACT stream in Flink, `update` message is finished by two stages, while when using UPSERT stream, it's finished by one stage, which is more efficient.

However, UPSERT stream is not allowed when converting a `Dynamic table` to a `DataStream` according to [this page](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/concepts/dynamic_tables/#table-to-stream-conversion), why such a limitation exists? What kinds of problems will be met when we totally replace RETRACT with UPSERT in Flink's design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What kinds of problems will be met when we totally replace RETRACT with UPSERT in Flink's design?

As the page you linked to mentions, upsert streams require a primary key. Getting rid of retract streams as a concept, consequently, would break all scenarios where you do not have such a key (at all or just not defined).